# Twig Change parent Twig's variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I have 2 Twigs: `Twig1`, `Twig2`. I included `Twig2` in `Twig1`.

In `Twig1` I have declared variable `foo`. How can I change `Twig1` `foo` variable from `Twig2` by `'reference'`?

```
// Twig1
{% set a = 5 %}
{{ include(Twig2) }}
{{ a }} //expected 50 got 5
```

Twig2

```
// Twig2
{% set a = 50 %}
```

Comment: Piece of advice: Don't "bold" you question in such way. It really deflects any necessary attention.

Comment: Can you provide sample code for your twig templates and symfony2 usage?

Answer (score 1):

As per `Twig` official [**docs**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html):

> Included templates have access to the variables of the active context.

So, just do:

```
{% set foo = "something else" %}
```

Hope I understood what you meant...

### Edit:

I think that's one of differences between `{% include %}` and `{{ include }}`. If I'm right, the first one has **direct access** to context, while the second one gets the context passed to it. So, depending on what you really want to accomplish, you could do:

```
// Twig1
{% set a = 5 %}
{% include "Twig2" %}
{{ a }} //expected 50 got 5

// Twig2
{% set a = 50 %}
```

Does this work?

### Edit 2:

Seems it's not possible after all. Extensive explanation [**here**](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/include-a-template-that-sets-variables-global-template-variables).

Comment: Your answer is correct,but I need another thing.I need that after including twig2, 'foo' variable will be changed in twig1.

Comment: No honestly the include is done with that way.With {% %} method